# Can a single Google Services API used on a specific ecommerce platform (Magento 2) be used on a different one (SAP Commerce Cloud)

Tags: e-commerce, magento2, sap-commerce-cloud, location-services

Our business is currently replatforming from Magento 2 to SAP Commerce Cloud. Can we use our current Google Places API be used on our new platform which will be SAP Commerce Cloud? Or do we need to get a new API?

If the latter applies, how can we go about getting a new places API and URL key?

I tried logging a ticket with the Google Business API team but they said this is a Places API issue but I can't seem to log a ticket with them directly.